# Install Qwt on Win7 64bit

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, qt, visual-studio-2012, qwt

I searched around the web but didn't find a solution for my proper problem.

**Problem:** Qwt-installation failes at the `nmake`-step

What I did:

-) installed Qt 5.1 (*Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 525 MB)*) (Info)from [qt-website](http://qt-project.org/downloads)

-) Downloaded *Qwt 6.1.0* files from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qwt/files/qwt/6.1.0/)

-) extracted Files to C:/Qt/Qwt-6.1.0

-) set correct path in qwtconfig.pri

-) started MSVC 2012 console (coming with Qt) and run `qmake qwt.pro`

-) tried `nmake` in same consol (but nmake.exe was not found)

--> installed Microsoft Visual 2010 Express from [here](http://www.chip.de/downloads/Visual-C-2010-Express_24081894.html) (automatically installed to 'Program Files (x86)')

-) tried again in aboves consol `nmake` but now with link to installed MSVC 2010 (but now comes fatal error U1077)

-) next I tried the consol coming with MSVC 2010 and again ran `nmake` (now I get fatal error LNK1112, which tells my x64PC is not compatible with target type x86)

**Question:** how can I make it work?

Comment: why voting down without comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***now I get fatal error LNK1112, which tells my x64PC is not compatible with target type x86***
Your problem is you installed the 64 bit Qt then you are trying to build Qwt in 32 bit mode. You can not link 32 bit code to 64 bit code or viseversa.

Make sure you have a 64 bit compiler if you want to build a 64 bit application. Visual Studio 2010 Express does not come with a 64 bit compiler. The following should help with that:

[How to compile a 64-bit application using Visual C++ 2010 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865069/how-to-compile-a-64-bit-application-using-visual-c-2010-express)

After you get a 64 bit compiler I believe you should run configure and nmake from a Visual Studio x64 command prompt to get the compiler to build 64 bit applications.

If you really do not need 64 bit applications a much easier approach is to install the 32 bit Qt SDK for Visual Studio 2010.

Here is the link for that:
http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.1/qt-windows-opensource-5.1.1-msvc2010_opengl-x86-offline.exe

Remember that you can develop and execute 32 bit applications under 64 bit windows.

[Will win32 bit applications run on a 64 bit server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222160/will-win-32-bit-applications-run-on-a-64-bit-server)

Comment: What do you mean by "need" 64bit applications, because I have 64 bit system and just want to try out and learn... if I have the 32 bit version working, will I be able to write programs for 32bit win7 and 64bit win7? If so, then I might really consider reinstalling the 32bit versions.

Comment: You can develop 32 bit applications on x64 versions of windows. The main reason for needing a 64 bit applications is if your program need to access more than 2GB of memory. If your programs do not need that use the 32 bit versions.

Comment: I updated my answer a little to address the 32bit development and execution question.

Comment: Thanks up to now, I will test that tomorrow on my pc and tag the question afterwards.

Comment: An important thing one has to keep in mind that you cannot link 32bit library to a 64bit application which basically means that your whole application must be 32bit.